Google Play shows "not compatible with your device" despite device being listed as compatible in Play Console
I have a React Native (Expo) app published on Google Play Store with

minSdkVersion: 23
targetSdkVersion: 34
compileSdkVersion: 34

The app works correctly when installed directly via APK, and it is installable via Google Play for a lot of users.
Issue:
Two devices I tried it on cannot find the app on Google Play, and when accessed directly through a link, they receive a "Your device isn't compatible with this version" message. However:

These same devices are listed as compatible in Google Play Console's device catalog
The app works when installed via direct APK
Enough time has passed (a week) since the app was published for Play Store caches to update
The devices are in the correct region (app is region-restricted to Czech Republic)
Both were devices where I tested the app using .apk before releasing it - however, than package has already been uninstalled
Both accounts are 18+ years old

Affected Devices:

Realme 6 (Android 11)
some Samsung (Android 9)
Not sure how many more devices - these are just the two I tried

Technical Details:

Using Android Google Play App Bundle format (.aab)
No explicit hardware/feature requirements in AndroidManifest.xml (no uses-feature, no required:true)
No explicit screen size or RAM requirements and no explicit device exclusion rules in Play Console

Relevant AndroidManifest.xml permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

Relevant part of app.config.ts:
const config: ExpoConfig = {
  // ... other config
  android: {
    package: "com.acme.app",
    userInterfaceStyle: "light",
    permissions: ["com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"],
    blockedPermissions: [],
    googleServicesFile: "./google-services.json",
    adaptiveIcon: {
      foregroundImage: "./assets/adaptive-icon/adaptive_icon_fg.png",
      backgroundColor: "#ffe3a5",
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    ["expo-apple-authentication"],
    [
      "expo-location",
      {
        locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission: `...`,
        locationWhenInUsePermission: `...`,
        isAndroidForegroundServiceEnabled: true,
      },
    ],
    ["expo-secure-store"],
    ["expo-localization"],
    [
      "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin",
      {
        iosUrlScheme: "com.googleusercontent.apps.[redacted]",
      },
    ],
    [
      "expo-build-properties",
      {
        android: {
          kotlinVersion: "1.7.22",
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};

What could be causing this discrepancy between Play Store compatibility and actual device compatibility? How can I resolve this issue?
